# Laravel 5.7 error 404 handling page location

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I couldn't find the location of the error 404 page in Laravel 5.7 please help.
here is the error page photo : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYpwa.jpg

Comment: root\resources\views\errors\404.blade.php

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find it here:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php
```

You shouldn't be editing this file directly though. If you want to add your custom error page just add an errors folder inside the resources/views and create your own 404.blade.php as desired. It will be used instead of Laravel's one.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote without comments, but all Laravel default exceptions and extended views for exceptions are located here: my_project_folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/

Comment: You didn't explained how to modify it. Just throwing a path makes the OP think that he can just change this file and everything goes fine, but actually, he can't since the file will be reloaded at every `composer install` or `composer update`. You answer should be just a comment, not answer. @ilubis answer is a little more complete.

Comment: You're right, should have explained it, but the question was specifically about the path, that's what I answered, I'll edit now to add the right action to take here

Answer (score 3):

actually you can override it in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

and set the code look like this.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;


class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->view('error_404_path', [], 404);
            // abort(404);
        }
        return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: if statements are not allowed inside a class, it should be included inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

With every change to the framework by updating, you will override any core function. 
Add an `errors` folder in your `views` directory, and place blade files with the error number you wish to modify.

For example:

`resources->views->errors->404.blade.php`

will be shown on 404 responses. And by the way, if you love(like me) the news errors svg, you can find the in `public->svg` folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you run php artisan vendor:publish you can see a list of vendor / package files that can be published for editing.

In the list you will see laravel-errors

Type the corresponding number then you will see.

Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views] To [/resources/views/errors]
Publishing complete.

You can then edit all the default error pages, including 404.blade.php 500.blade.php etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command in terminal/cmd to show all error blades in the view directory and then you can edit them :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

also, you can show your arbitrary blade for just 404 error in route by fallback. for example :

```
Route::fallback(function () {
return view('myCustum404Error');
});
```